# Android SQLite no such table / prepopulated database

Tags: android, sqlite

I prepoluate a sqlite database in my application based on this article: 
[a link] http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

So the database will be created/copied/opened successfully (DDMS, File Explorer, ...). In the next step i would like to insert some data into a table. And then i get the "no such table" error and i don´t unterstand why.

**CREATE / OPEN DATABASE**

```
public void createSQLite() {
    try {
        helper.createDataBase();
        helper.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**NAME AND ATTRIBUTES OT TABLE**

```
    public static final String cust_id = "customer_id_fk";
public static final String app_cust_id = "app_cust_id_pk";
public static final String hash = "app_hashvalue";
public static final String version = "app_version";
public static final String date = "activation_date";
public static final String handy = "handynr";
public static final String device = "devicename";
public static final String active = "activated";
public static final String APP_CUSTOMER = "app_customer";
```

**INSERT INTO TABE**

```
public void addAppCustomer(Activation act) {        

    long rowId = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlite.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();

    // Create values
    val.put(app_cust_id, act.getApp_customer_id());
    val.put(cust_id, act.getCustomer_id());
    val.put(hash, act.getImei());
    val.put(version, act.getAppversion());
    val.put(date, act.getActivationDate());
    val.put(handy, act.getPhone_number());
    val.put(device, act.getDevice_name());
    val.put(active, act.getActivated());
    rowId = db.insert(APP_CUSTOMER, null, val);
}
```

Once again:database / table is created. When trying to insert the data above i get "no such table" error (app_customer).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

**CREATE TABLE STATEMENT**

```
    CREATE TABLE `app_customer` (
      `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      `app_cust_id_pk` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `customer_id_fk` INTEGER NOT NULL,
      `app_hashvalue` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
      `app_version` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `activation_date` NUMERIC NOT NULL,
      `handynr` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
      `devicename` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `activated` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    )
```

Comment: could you post the create table statement ??

Comment: Please consider using something more modern than that five-year-old blog post, such [as `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: I´ve updatet my question (see CREATE TABLE).